Calculating richness of text from NLTK book package
I am trying to return richness of NLTK text provided in NLTK book but for some reason I get None.
Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong?
from nltk.book import *

def lexical_diversity_of_nltk_text(text_input):

    books = [text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6, text7, text8, text9]

    if text_input in books:
            richness =  len(text_input)/len(set(text_input))

        return richness 

text_input = input('Please enter the number of text as in example - "text1": ')

print(lexical_diversity_of_nltk_text(text_input))

I am expecting to get richness of the text from ntlk book.package

The text_input variable is a string, it comes from input(). However, the books list contains NLTK Text objects (e.g., text1, text2), not their string names. When you check if text_input in books, it will return False because a string is not the same as the object.
Use a dictionary to map the string names to the corresponding NLTK Text objects. Then, check if text_input is a valid key in the dictionary.
def lexical_diversity_of_nltk_text(text_input):
    books = {
        "text1": text1,
        "text2": text2,
        "text3": text3,
        "text4": text4,
        "text5": text5,
        "text6": text6,
        "text7": text7,
        "text8": text8,
        "text9": text9
    }
    
    if text_input in books:
        text = books[text_input]
        richness = len(text) / len(set(text))
        return richness
    else:
        return None

